# C# Message Box Pops up Repeatedly in a Timer

Tags: c#, messagebox

Someone else had a similar question as I do; but they didn't actually get an answer that worked. I can get this to work by creating a bool and setting it to false once it gets into the if statement. I have done it before using that method, BUT, I want to know if there is a cleaner way.

**The Question:** *Why is it that when I use a message box in a timer with a simple okay button, that someone has to click okay; otherwise you get the same message every second? In the code below; it pops up every one second as that is what the timer is set to do (tick by one second), but it should only display one time when the timer hits 10 like in the code below, but the timer should still be "ticking" since it shows in a label.*

Before someone tears me to shreds as I've noticed people like to do on here for some reason; my logic says that since seconds = 10, it should display one time. When seconds = 11, it doesn't make sense that it would display an additional box because it's 11 not 10. I would like to know what causes that as well?

```
private void randomtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (seconds == 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this,"Why does this message display every one second over and over until someone clicks close or okay?");
        }
        seconds++;            
        if (seconds >= 60)
        {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = minutes + 1;  
        }
        if (minutes >= 60)
        {
            minutes = 0;
            hours = hours + 1;
        }

        string niceTime = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", hours, minutes, seconds); //format the time so it displays nicely
        label2.Text = "Session Length:\n" + niceTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is, because you aren't incrementing `seconds` until after the `MessageBox.Show()`.  Move it before the `if (seconds == 10)` test and your code will work.

The execution flow stops at `MessageBox.Show()` and then another Time event fires.  You must always use care with re-entry when it comes to timers.

Comment: That is so simple and so embarrassing.

Comment: I didn't think you'd need any more code than what I included :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That did fix it. I didn't think about it till I read what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain this as simple as I can so bear with me.

When the timer's handler is called the counter will not be blocked. Each second (timer's interval) the function you provided runs. Now, when you show the `MessageBox`, the thread of the timer's handler gets blocked. Hence, your code which increases the second will not run until the user clicks *OK* and the function resumes.

Now, if the user doesn't press OK, the second will get stuck at 10. After 1 second, the timer will call the handler again and your `if` will run because the value is still at 10.

If you want to prevent this, use a code like this one:

```
        if (seconds == 10)
        {
            seconds++;
            MessageBox.Show(this,"Why does this message display every one second over and over until someone clicks close or okay?");
        }
        else
            seconds++;
```

Of course there are better ways, but this will work.

Comment: Disagree, this is most likely a `Windows.Forms.Timer` which is on the GUI thread.  Buut it hsa it's own message pump so events can still fire.

Comment: That also makes sense. I didn't really think about that. Although; it was still adding seconds correctly with the addition of each message box. But I believe I do understand what you are saying. Still learning a few things with this. Again; thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @tcarvin Thanks for the info. I don't know if it is the UI thread or not. I can write a timer which uses another thread without the problems that one may think but in the end I think you're right. I'll try to come up with a better sentence for that part.

Comment: @tcarvin I searched around and couldn't find a specific answer. What I think (and said in my answer) is that the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has its own thread for counting and whenever it hits the interval, it calls the handler on the UI thread. That's what I would do if I was writing the timer.

Comment: @tcarvin If you had any document that says otherwise, please kindly post it to me so that I can read it. Thanks.

Comment: "A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread."  from the MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> **that someone has to click okay; otherwise you get the same message every second?**

Now, that's your problem. Look at the code again:

```
if (seconds == 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this,"Why does this message display every one second over and over until someone clicks close or okay?");
}
seconds++;
```

Seconds isn't incremented until after the `MessageBox.Show` is dismissed. Change it to this:

```
if (seconds == 10)
{
    seconds++;
    MessageBox.Show(this,"Why does this message display every one second over and over until someone clicks close or okay?");
}
else seconds++;
```

and that will fix your problem.

Comment: In that case it will run on the 9th second. You should change it to `if (seconds == 11)`

Comment: Yes; that did fix it. It has happened to me before; but it was intermittent and now I know why. Thank you also for the quick response.